# Visual Studio 2015 doesn't honour _Check_return_ or _Must_inspect_result_

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, cross-platform, compiler-warnings

I have a cross-platform build. On a *nix platform using GCC, I use the `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))` to notify the consumer of my API if a return value is not checked. I assumed that `_Check_return` does the same thing on MSVC, but it doesn't appear to be working the way I expect.

The following code does not produce a warning as I expect. Warnings are set to `/Wall`.

```
_Check_return_ _Must_inspect_result_ int foo()
{
    return 100;
}


int main()
{
    foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Code compiles without warnings. What am I doing wrong (or what should I be using to generate warnings for unchecked return codes)?

Answer (score 4):

SAL annotations like `_Check_return_` and `_Must_inspect_result_` are only checked during code analysis builds (either by starting a code analysis build in the IDE or by building with the /analyze flag on the command line).

See ["Understanding SAL"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh916383.aspx) on MSDN for more information.

Comment: I see. Is there any way to enforce return code checking without `/analyze` on VC++ builds? I'm looking for a VC++ analog to `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))`.

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no.